# Moment of Conditional Probability Rules

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I have this question in my textbook:
[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNsI5.png)

There is this part of the solution from the text book: [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5bRL.png)

I still dont get the yellow part that says
$$
E[Y^2|W=w]=E[2W^2]
$$
Can somebody explain that?

Thanks in advance. Best regards.